# How to call the few pages before the actual content of a book?

Tags: word-request

That may include the Book title page, Copyright page, preface page, content table page, etc.
or just the Book title page and the Copyright page.

Answer (score 1):

Those are included in "front matter", followed by "body" and "back matter":

[scribendi "front matter"](https://www.scribendi.com/academy/articles/front_matter.en.html)

> Front matter is the first section of a book and is generally the shortest; it is also sometimes called the prelims, or preliminary matter. It can be as simple as a single title page, or it can include multiple title pages, foreword, a preface, and much more. What is included in front matter really depends on the type of publication, so let's go over some of the possibilities.